# Stop the wizard implicitly opting me into receiving emails if I've disabled email notifications

Tags: bug, email, ask-question-wizard

When I try posting a question using the Ask Wizard, I fill both parts of the body, then fill in tags, then click to review my question. At that point there is a checkbox at the bottom that says "Email me new responses to my posts" and it is enabled by default:

[image: The checkbox is selected in the Ask Wizard just before the "Post your question" button"]

[See GIF of filling the Ask Wizard form and getting "Email me new responses to my posts" by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhDMs.gif)

This is ***only*** the case in the Ask Wizard. In the regular ask page, if I fill in the details for the question then click on "Review your question" the checkbox shows and it is not checked:

[image: The checkbox is not selected in the regular Ask just before the "Post your question" button]

[See GIF of filling the regular ask form and "Email me new responses to my posts" is not selected by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gfKh.png)

If I switch between the Ask Wizard and the regular ask page, the option "Email me new responses to my posts" is consistently checked in the Ask Wizard and consistently off for the regular page.

**NOTE:** The only reason to get the checkbox is if in your user settings under "Edit email settings" the setting "Inbox" is set to "Off". That triggers the "Email me new responses to my posts" option to show when posting. I certainly do *not* want this to happen and it is disabled in the regular view. The Ask Wizard is inconsistent here as the old Ask page never defaulted it to enabled.

The wizard defaulting to opting me *into* emails I have already said I do not want must be a bug.

Comment: 'our data has shown that sending users emails results in increased page visits'

Comment: Follow-up (from Askers) is the "Number 1" Frustration for Answerers in "small Tags", so I'm glad if they get a pushed Notif about Comments/Answers... Should need at least 100-Rep and regular Site Visiting to be able to switch off Notifs...

Comment: This is a 'dark pattern', so even if it was an intentional change it is bad and should be altered.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)

(convert the following into all caps:) Now I've finally found out why my email settings for inbox notification were "randomly" getting switched from "Off" to "3 hrs".

Please also fix that.